# read dot file for graphviz without storing node-id in boost graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have a file named "test.dot" something like,

```
graph {
    0;
    1;
    0 -- 1;
}
//EOF
```

I want to read a file using boost graph library.

```
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int,char*[])
{
    typedef adjacency_list< vecS, vecS, undirectedS, property<vertex_color_t,int> > Graph;
    Graph g(0);

    dynamic_properties dp;
    auto index = get(vertex_color, g);
    dp.property("node_id", index);

    ifstream fin("test.dot");
    read_graphviz(fin, g, dp);
}
```

However, in this source code, I had to attach another property(vertex_color_t) to store "node_id".
In my simple example, it is just the same as "node_index".

Is there a way that I can identify them to save memory?? I don't want to introduce additional property.

Comment: Where is `node_index` in the code?  Is just changing the name of the `node_id` property (see the `read_graphviz` documentation for how to do that) enough?

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic_properties` has a constructor which accepts a functor to handle the default case, one implementation is `boost::ignore_other_properties`. This works:

```
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int,char*[])
{
    typedef adjacency_list< vecS, vecS, undirectedS > Graph;
    Graph g(0);

    dynamic_properties dp(ignore_other_properties);
    ifstream fin("test.dot");
    read_graphviz(fin, g, dp);
}
```